# prove $\frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}<1$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can you help prove that $\frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}<1$, for all positive $x\neq 1$ and $c$ a positive integer?

Comment: Yes, but you should show your attempt (even if little)

Comment: BTW, note that if $c$ is odd, then $x \ne -1$, too.

Comment: I only need it for positive $x$. I don't have any progress with it to show. only numerical.

Comment: Can $c$ be a negative integer as well?

Comment: No, I have fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}=1-\frac{1-x}{1-x^{c+1}}=1-\frac{1}{1+x+x^2..+x^c}< 1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $$\frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}<1 \\ \frac{x- x^{c+1} - 1 + x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}} < 0 \\ \frac{x-1}{1-x^{c+1}} < 0$$

Comment: (+1) for combining the fractions. Plus this works if $c$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

1, If $\;0<x<1\;$, then

$$x^c<1\implies 1-x^c>0\implies \frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}<1\iff x-x^{c+1}<1-x^{c+1}\iff x<1\;\;\checkmark$$

2.- if $\;x>1\;$,  then

$$x^{c+1}>1\implies 1-x^{c+1}<0\implies\frac{x-x^{c+1}}{1-x^{c+1}}<1\iff x-x^{c+1}>1-x^{c+1}\iff x>1\;\checkmark$$